# Android: AppCompatActivity and textview inside the action bar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

I want to add an autocompletetextview component inside the action bar of a AppCompatActivity. My code is:

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GlobalException());

        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
}
```

layout/action_bar_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/theSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_the"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When my app opens, I see a blank white screen and after several seconds, it becomes a blank black screen that stays this way forever, until I stop it manually. Any idea?

Apparently, after `Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);` tb is null

Comment: I think more information can be found in the stacktrace, arent you getting any exceptions?

Comment: There is no exception, it's as if it's running in the background doing something while all I see is a black screen, after it was white for a few seconds

Comment: Hm. Well the code you provided seems fine so there are a lot of reasons why your app can hang. Like a infinite loop for example. So without a stacktrace this would be guessing at best.

Comment: I had additional code that I removed (forgot I didn't comment it out) so now it works but there is nothing as the actionbar/toolbar at the top. That might explains the behavior I wrote about, as if the toolbar and component are not there

Comment: So your `Toolbar` is null? Is the `Toobar` XML in `R.layout.activity_main`?

Comment: No, it's in its own xml: layout/action_bar_search.xml

Comment: But it has to be included in `R.layout_activity_main` otherwise `findById` will not work.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it when you asked the question. Now I moved it into activity_main. How can I include it in activity_main if I want to reserve it in its own file? Also, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, i've added the answer. Glad to've helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Toolbar` XML is not included in your `R.layout.activity_main` so `findById` will not work. This results in the `Toolbar` staying null and crashing your application. You can include layout resources with an `<include>` tag. In your case: `<include layout="@layout/action_bar_search"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example code for AutocompleteTextView:

```
AutoCompleteTextView text;
String[] languages={"Android ","java","IOS","SQL","JDBC","Web services"};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.theSearch);
  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
  text.setAdapter(adapter);
  text.setThreshold(1);    
  }
```

I hope that will help you....

Comment: It looks like the problem is deeper because of the symptom I wrote above (white/black blank screen).

Comment: The question is what's wrong with what I have done. Copy paste other code is not really helpful :) I expected to see the autocomplete text view at least but that's not what is happening

Comment: in that case the problem would be something else....coz the code is working fine on my side....

Comment: The problem seems to be in action_bar_search.xml ...could u recreate this file

Comment: problem in what way? by recreate you mean delete the file and copy paste its content into a new one?

Comment: Just create recreate_bar_search and copy paste AutoCompleteTextView code

Comment: I had additional code that I removed (forgot I didn't comment it out) so now it works but there is nothing as the actionbar/toolbar at the top.  That might explains the behavior I wrote about, as if the toolbar and component are not there

Comment: U have to add some code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu> in your menu_main.xml to get it search icon shown in your toolbar . Remember to download an icon 'ic_search'

Comment: but the whole actionbar is missing. Also I'm confused. To add something to the actionbar, I need to use the layout or the menu?